# Glassfish won't start, how to reset glassfish instance?

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, derby, realm

I made a change in my glassfish jdbc resource pool via the admin console, my last change was a realm configuration where I renamed the user table field from "tablename" to "db"."tablename" as an attempt to get jdbcrealm auth working with a derby db but now my glassfish instance won't start. I've uninstalled and reinstalled netbeans and glassfish and am currently getting this error:

```
SEVERE: RAR8061: failed to load resource-adapter-config or RA [ __ds_jdbc_ra ], com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.ConnectorRuntimeException: Unable to get active RA for module __ds_jdbc_ra
SEVERE: RAR8060: Unable to lookup pool [ SamplePool ], javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for '__SYSTEM/pools/SamplePool' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: pools]
SEVERE: RAR6017 : Failed to get connection pool object jdbc/sample via JNDI lookup : com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.ConnectorRuntimeException: Lookup failed for '__SYSTEM/pools/SamplePool' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming}
SEVERE: java.util.logging.ErrorManager: 5: Error in formatting Logrecord
SEVERE: java.lang.RuntimeException: Lookup failed for 'jdbc/sample' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming}
    at org.glassfish.osgi.ee.resources.ResourceProxy.getActualObject(ResourceProxy.java:83)
    at org.glassfish.osgi.ee.resources.ResourceProxy.invoke(ResourceProxy.java:69)
    at $Proxy170.toString(Unknown Source)
    at java.text.MessageFormat.subformat(MessageFormat.java:1246)
    at java.text.MessageFormat.format(MessageFormat.java:836)
    at java.text.Format.format(Format.java:140)
    at java.text.MessageFormat.format(MessageFormat.java:812)
    at com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.UniformLogFormatter.uniformLogFormat(UniformLogFormatter.java:330)
    at com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.UniformLogFormatter.format(UniformLogFormatter.java:162)
    at java.util.logging.StreamHandler.publish(StreamHandler.java:179)
    at java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.publish(ConsoleHandler.java:88)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.log(Logger.java:478)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.doLog(Logger.java:500)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.logp(Logger.java:669)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.osgiadapter.HK2Main$HK2ServiceTrackerCustomizer.addingService(HK2Main.java:284)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker$Tracked.customizerAdding(ServiceTracker.java:980)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker$Tracked.customizerAdding(ServiceTracker.java:906)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.AbstractTracked.trackAdding(AbstractTracked.java:262)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.AbstractTracked.track(AbstractTracked.java:234)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker$Tracked.serviceChanged(ServiceTracker.java:941)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.util.EventDispatcher.invokeServiceListenerCallback(EventDispatcher.java:932)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.util.EventDispatcher.fireEventImmediately(EventDispatcher.java:793)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.util.EventDispatcher.fireServiceEvent(EventDispatcher.java:543)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.fireServiceEvent(Felix.java:4260)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.registerService(Felix.java:3275)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:346)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:320)
    at org.glassfish.osgi.ee.resources.BaseResourceManager.registerResourceAsService(BaseResourceManager.java:131)
    at org.glassfish.osgi.ee.resources.JDBCResourceManager.registerJdbcResource(JDBCResourceManager.java:110)
    at org.glassfish.osgi.ee.resources.JDBCResourceManager.registerJdbcResources(JDBCResourceManager.java:74)
    at org.glassfish.osgi.ee.resources.JDBCResourceManager.registerResources(JDBCResourceManager.java:62)
    at org.glassfish.osgi.ee.resources.ResourceProviderService.registerResources(ResourceProviderService.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.osgi.ee.resources.ResourcesExtender.start(ResourcesExtender.java:72)
    at org.glassfish.osgijavaeebase.ExtenderManager$ExtenderTracker.addingService(ExtenderManager.java:142)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker$Tracked.customizerAdding(ServiceTracker.java:980)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker$Tracked.customizerAdding(ServiceTracker.java:906)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.AbstractTracked.trackAdding(AbstractTracked.java:262)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.AbstractTracked.trackInitial(AbstractTracked.java:185)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker.open(ServiceTracker.java:348)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker.open(ServiceTracker.java:283)
    at org.glassfish.osgijavaeebase.ExtenderManager.startExtenders(ExtenderManager.java:108)
    at org.glassfish.osgijavaeebase.ExtenderManager.access$300(ExtenderManager.java:66)
    at org.glassfish.osgijavaeebase.ExtenderManager$GlassFishServerTracker.addingService(ExtenderManager.java:185)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker$Tracked.customizerAdding(ServiceTracker.java:980)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker$Tracked.customizerAdding(ServiceTracker.java:906)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.AbstractTracked.trackAdding(AbstractTracked.java:262)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.AbstractTracked.trackInitial(AbstractTracked.java:185)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker.open(ServiceTracker.java:348)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker.open(ServiceTracker.java:283)
    at org.glassfish.osgijavaeebase.ExtenderManager.start(ExtenderManager.java:85)
    at org.glassfish.osgijavaeebase.OSGiJavaEEActivator.start(OSGiJavaEEActivator.java:66)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.util.SecureAction.startActivator(SecureAction.java:641)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.activateBundle(Felix.java:1977)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:1895)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1191)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkStartLevelImpl.run(FrameworkStartLevelImpl.java:295)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'jdbc/sample' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Unable to lookup resource : jdbc/sample [Root exception is com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.ConnectorRuntimeException: Lookup failed for '__SYSTEM/pools/SamplePool' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming}]]
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:518)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:455)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:392)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:392)
    at org.glassfish.osgi.ee.resources.ResourceProxy.getActualObject(ResourceProxy.java:81)
    ... 56 more
Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: Unable to lookup resource : jdbc/sample [Root exception is com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.ConnectorRuntimeException: Lookup failed for '__SYSTEM/pools/SamplePool' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming}]
    at org.glassfish.javaee.services.ResourceProxy.throwResourceNotFoundException(ResourceProxy.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.services.ResourceProxy.create(ResourceProxy.java:95)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:507)
    ... 60 more
Caused by: com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.ConnectorRuntimeException: Lookup failed for '__SYSTEM/pools/SamplePool' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming}
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.service.ConnectorResourceAdminServiceImpl.createConnectorResource(ConnectorResourceAdminServiceImpl.java:151)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectorRuntime.createConnectorResource(ConnectorRuntime.java:297)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.deployer.JdbcResourceDeployer.deployResource(JdbcResourceDeployer.java:106)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.services.ResourceProxy.create(ResourceProxy.java:90)
    ... 61 more
Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for '__SYSTEM/pools/SamplePool' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: pools]
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:518)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:
SEVERE: 455)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:392)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:392)
    at com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.ResourceNamingService.lookup(ResourceNamingService.java:223)
    at com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.ResourceNamingService.lookup(ResourceNamingService.java:230)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.service.ConnectorResourceAdminServiceImpl.createConnectorResource(ConnectorResourceAdminServiceImpl.java:111)
    ... 64 more
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: pools
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext.resolveContext(TransientContext.java:310)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext.lookup(TransientContext.java:218)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext.lookup(TransientContext.java:219)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContextProviderImpl.lookup(SerialContextProviderImpl.java:77)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.LocalSerialContextProviderImpl.lookup(LocalSerialContextProviderImpl.java:119)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:505)
    ... 70 more
```

Is there a way to reset my glassfish instance to its defaults so i can start using it again?

Answer (score 3):

If you are using the Netbeans bundled Glassfish 3.1.2, the domain.xml configuration file is automatically backed up when a change is made. I believe that the default location for Windows is C:\Program Files\glassfish-3.1.2\glassfish\domains\domain1\config.

Look for domain.xml.bak. Save a copy of your current domain.xml and replace it with domain.xml.bak and start the server.

Older versions of NetBeans store the glassfish configuration in the C:\users directory which isn't completely removed when the program is uninstalled. That is why the problem still exists even after reinstallation.

Comment: you saved my day! added a lifecycle module that failed to load and thus made the server not load!!! so was left with no option on how to disable it...